# Is it quicker to pass NSData comparing to UIImage

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to optimising the performance of my app. I was wondering if there is a difference (speed wise) if I pass the NSData version of an UIImage to another View Controller?

I am converting the NSData via the following code

```
extension UIImage {
    var uncompressedPNGData: NSData {
       return UIImagePNGRepresentation(self)!       
    }
}
```

And here is how I pass image Data. As you can see, there is alot of passing. 
Custom photo browser select an image and pass it to the next VC

```
PHImageManager.defaultManager().requestImageForAsset(self.albumView.phAsset, targetSize: targetSize,
contentMode: .AspectFill, options: options) {
    result, info in

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let postVC = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("PostVC") as! PostVC
        postVC.imageFromPreviousVC = result!
        self.navigationController!.pushViewController(postVC, animated: true)
    })
}
```

In viewDidLoad of PostVC, I assign the passed imaged to an imageView

```
selectedImageView.image = self.imageFromPreviousVC
```

And if the user clicked on the image, the image is zoomed to a newVC

```
let storyboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ZoomedVC") as! ZoomedVC
vc.imageFromPreviousVC = selectedImageView.image!
self.presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: Are you passing by reference?? If yes then sending image reference is faster because for passing the NSData you need to convert the image to data, so that would be the extra time needed in case of NSData

Comment: I have included more code, I dont think that is passing by reference (How could I tell??)

Comment: This is called passing by reference, as you are actually passing the reference of the images, in this case if you change the image in the next controller the image of previous controller is also get changed. This is the concept of Shallow copy. So I can say if you have the image then you should pass it without converting.

Comment: So if it is passing by copy, without considering conversion time, is it quicker to pass the NSData version of the UIImage?

Comment: It would take same time whether you pass image or data (if you consider without conversion time).